# Is async code that easy?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

I am working on a C# Hue application, I am creating the api calls myself for the learning experience. Since Hue consists of many network calls i wanted to also provide an async method for every sync method i create. I wrote some lines of code and thought to myself "This can't possibly be so easy", so now I'm here and wanted to ask if this is a good way to implement async functions? Also any other optimizations to my code are appreciated.

```
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace SharpHue
{
    public class HueUtilities
    {
        const string DISCOVERY_URI = "http://www.meethue.com/api/nupnp";

        public struct DiscoveryElement
        {
            [JsonProperty("id")]
            public string ID;
            [JsonProperty("internalipaddress")]
            public string Address;
        }

        public static DiscoveryElement[] DiscoverBridges() 
        {
            string data = "[]";
            var request = WebRequest.CreateHttp(DISCOVERY_URI);
            try
            {
                var response = request.GetResponse();
                using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
                {
                    data = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
                    streamReader.Close();
                    response.Close();
                }
                return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DiscoveryElement[]>(data);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }

        public static async Task<DiscoveryElement[]> DiscoverBridgesAsync() 
        {
            return await Task.Run(() => DiscoverBridges());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Essentially, all IO code must be duplicated. This is a severe burden on productivity and maintenance. So think about whether callers will need/want both styles. You can also use sync over async to provide sync convenience wrappers at a fairly small perf cost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Almost. But you should avoid Task.Run when there are true async alternatives. In your case that means replacing WebRequest class with HttpClient and call your code like this:

```
public static async Task<DiscoveryElement[]> DiscoverBridgesAsync() 
{
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        var result = await client.GetAsync(DISCOVERY_URI);
        return await result.Content.ReadAsAsync<DiscoveryElement[]>();     
    }
}
```

As you can see there is no more use for the method that wrapped the synchronous call to an async call. It's now truly async/await compliant.

*warning* There might be some compile errors but should work.

More info: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/advanced/calling-a-web-api-from-a-net-client

And please, read this: http://www.ben-morris.com/why-you-shouldnt-create-asynchronous-wrappers-with-task-run/

Comment: It works just fine :) These methods should exist in parallel - you should be able to call sync and call async when needed. Would you recommend rewriting the sync method as well or leave it be?

Comment: @Benedikt: I recommend just keeping the async version, since this is an async operation. However, if you **must** keep both async/sync versions, and you want to avoid code duplication, then check out the "bool argument hack" in my [article on brownfield async development](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt238404.aspx).

Comment: @StephenCleary nice one! will remember that for my code as well :-)

Comment: @StephenCleary Yea, i think I'll just keep the async method. I had a quick look at the article - seems cool I might try it when needed.

Answer (score 0):

No `async` code is notoriously difficult to write that's why they added the `async` keyword. the problem tends to be that people don't understand what `async` code is and why use it. This code

```
var result = await Task.FromResult(0);
```

Is [similar](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/category/eduasync/) to writing

```
Task.FromResult(0).ContinueWith((task)=> 
            {
                var result = task.Result;
            });
```

If the code is not [Asynchronous](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj152938(v=vs.110).aspx) using async keyword wont make it so. Your code is Asynchronous because of what [Task.Run](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh195051(v=vs.110).aspx) dose, not the async Keyword. Stuff like `ReadStream` and `ReadstreamAsync` actually might do two completely different things like with [file access](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365683(v=vs.85).aspx).
Task.Run will not act the same in something like Asp.Net and Wpf since asp dose not have a UI thread. Also tasks have nothing to do with threads they can run on a single thread and do in some cases.[Akavache](https://github.com/akavache/Akavache) is grate example of how to do async programing on a single thread. You have to be carful using async if you don't understand what will be done in the background.